# What in the world is a .el8 file?

Tags: macos, video, file-extension

I am taking an online Latin class, and they gave me a video to watch.

A .el8.

What? el8? I have *never* heard of that in my life. It's supposed to be a video, so I tried renaming it to a .mov (Latin teachers not being known for computational excellence), but no dice.

I'm running OS X 10.8. How do I open this thing?

Running `file` on it shows:

```
/Users/admin/Desktop/U734806R4970S3962792726.mov: data
```

And the first few lines of looking at it in `vi` are as follows:

```
^@^@^@^@^[U734806R4970S3962792726.el8T^L°w<80> ú#^?^G^@^@<88> ú#Ä^@#^@ÀÚ°wsÒÑ³^@^@#^@^@ 
^@^@x^@ú#^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@üîÓ^P^Kê°wvp³wgÒÑ³^@^@#^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ -#^@^@^@^@^@^B^D^@^@à(D
^@^@^@^@^PÖh
^@^@#^@^B^D#%^@^@^@^@ -#^@þ^C^@^@TïÓ^Pðo³w^@^@^@^@^@^@#^@^@^@#^@ø;^@^@ÿ<9e>iê^DÀCä@âQ<8c>PÂCä@5^X^@^@^R7 ^A^@^@^@ÔîÓ^P>^\±w^@^@#^@à(D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@#^@à(D
^@^@#^@þ^C^@ý^D^@^@^@^XÖh
^XÖh
¸c0
þ^C^@^@~^C^@^@ÌïÓ^P×<93>³w^@^@#^@à(D
^@^H^@^@¢s³wWÓÑ³^@^@^@^@^@^@#^@è(D
<82>^C^@^@H.V
¨$î#^P ^@^@<94><82>¯w§ÓÑ³^B^D^@^@0.#^@^@^@^@^@^@^@#^@^PïÓ^P -#^@hïÓ^P^XÖh
H.V
xïÓ^P<9b><82>¯^@^@^@^@^@^@çiv^XÖh
^C^@^@^@<84>ïÓ^Phã°w0^A#^@¨^Fÿ^@þÿÿÿ¢s³wÕs³w^@^@^@^@^XÖh
<94><82>¯w?ÓÑ³^@^H^@^@è(D
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ò½^@^@;C:\eLecta\Server\TempRecordings\U734806R4970S3962792726.el8¢s³wÕs³w^@^@^@^@è(D
```

Comment: There is a clue in the temp path for the server recordings:  [http://www.e-lecta.com/](http://www.e-lecta.com/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The data vim showed you when you opened the binary file contained the string `eLecta`, which points me to [eLecta](http://www.e-lecta.com/), a virtual classroom software.

Since the software is commercial, your teacher should have supplied you with a player embedded in some web-site rather than a standalone download. [It uses Java](http://support.e-lecta.com/downloads/Version4/References/eLectaBrowserSysReq.pdf) to play the file.

Otherwise you can maybe try installing [the free trial](http://www.e-lecta.com/free-trial.asp) to play the file by setting up your own course.

Answer (score 7):

El8 can be played online only. Please ask your teacher to give you a playable link instead of a file.

Answer (score 4):

[FAQ: Publishing a recorded session which does not reside on the eLecta Live servers](http://support.e-lecta.com/eLectaKB/afmmain.aspx?faqid=113) mentions an online player for recorded sessions.

> B: Publishing a recorded session which does not reside on the eLecta Live servers
>
> - Log into your account;
> - Click on Manage Recorded Sessions from the Moderators menu;
> - Find the recording ->> click on More - >> click on the Download1 button and download the file locally on your computer.
> - Upload the same file to your server as if uploading a regular file. The location may look like:
>
> http://www.YourSite.com/YourFile.el7
>
> - Embed the following link on your site for your visitors: http://e-lectazone.com/tools/play_uni.asp?url=http://www.YourSite.com/YourFile.el7
>
> IMPORTANT
>
> You may need to configure your web site to allow the following mime types.
>
> .el8 - application/octetstream
>
> .el7 - application/octetstream
>
> .el6 - application/octetstream
>
> .el5 - application/octetstream
>
> .electa - application/octetstream
>
> Please refer to your web site hosting support documentation on how to add mime types.

Maybe this works for your .el8.
So you can upload it to a webserver, configuring the MIME-types accordingly if necessary, and start watching the show.

Comment: Seems crazy to have to use my server to watch a class, but it seems to be the best solution.

Comment: @Undo Didn't you get some link to actually watch the class on their servers?

Comment: I wonder *how many* students will be able to actually watch the video. And if the content will be required in a later exam...